Does a finite duration signal have finite effective （RMS） bandwidth?
A determined signal $s(t)$ with normalized energy, i.e.  $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|s(t)|^2dt=1$, whose effective bandwidth (or RMS bandwidth) is defined by $B=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(f-\hat{f})^2|S(f)|^2df$ , where $S(f)$ is the Fourier transform of $s(t)$ and $\hat{f}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f|S(f)|^2$. If the duration ( or support) of $s(t)$ is finite, I guess that $B$ is infinite. Is it ture?
The effective bandwidth is an important metric for delay estimation in radar.
Asumme the received signal is $x(t)=s(t-\tau)+n(t)$, where $\tau$ is the time delay and $n(t)$ is complex Gaussian white noise.
If the effective banndwidth is infinite， then the Cramer-Rao bound for the estimation of time delay will be zero. If my conjecture is true, many numerical experiments in the papers published in the signal processing society will be wrong.

Is that your definition of "effective bandwidth"?  If not, where have you seen it?  If so, why are you using it?

this is, by the way, a very strange definition of bandwidth. I'd say it's not very useful in practice. For example: Signal 1 has a PSD of exactly 1 between -1 Hz and +1Hz, zero everywhere else (any sensible definition would give that signal an bandwidth of 2Hz). According to your definition $B=\int_{-1}^{1}f^2 \mathrm df=\frac{2}{3}$, so one third of what it "should" be. Signal 2 concentrates same power in half the band, so it has PSD 2 between -0.5 Hz and +0.5 Hz; $B=\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} 2 f^2 \mathrm df=\frac{1}{6}$. That is only ¼ of the "effective" bw of the signal that was 2× as wide.

Even worse, it's not translation-invariant: you can take a signal with some $B$, then shift it up in frequency by even small amounts and that changes its bandwidth? Is that really a bandwidth?

@TimWescott  Thanks! I have revised  the question. The effective bandwidth is also  called the RMS bandwidth.

@Marcus Müller Sorry for the unclear description. I revised my question and add  a reference.

First of all, the definition is sensible for real valued signals. For complex signals you would want to use $(f-\hat{f})^2$ instead of $f^2$ in the integral, where $\hat{f}$ is the expectation of $f$ as in $\hat{f}=\int_\mathbb{R} f |S(f)|^2 df$. The answer to the OP's question is that a finite duration signal may have both a finite or an infinite effective bandwidth. Examples for each are easily constructed by choosing the rectangular signal as a finite duration signal with infinite effective BW. Its auto-convolutions are then of finite effective BW.

@Jazzmaniac Thanks for your answer.  I found many papers use  truncated single tone  $\exp(j2\pi f t), 0<t<T$,
in their numerical experiments. These signals have infinite bandwidth obviously.  I also  compute the effective BW of some LFM signals numerically  and  found that they
can not be bounded. So I post the question.  Is there a general method to determine whether the effective bandwidth of  a finite  duration signal is finite or infinite?

I fail to see what this B has to do with the Cramer-Rao lower bound? that makes a statement on estimation variance based on the variance of noise relative to the variance of signal, and the fact that the "effective bandwidth" is bounded or not is completely unrelated to the noise, or the signal, because, well, as illustrated above, it doesn't say anything about the signal's actual equivalent noise bandwidth. The same radar pulse at a slightly different frequency has a different B, without the noise affecting it changing at all. So, trying to conclude from $B$ on CRLB cannot work.

Thus, trying to argue about whether B is bound for time-limited signals (it's not) is a completely moot point.

The relationship between CRLR of time delay estimation and the effective bandwidth  can be found in Chapter 10 of Van Trees's book titled "Detection, Estimation, and Modulation Theory, Part III". You can download it from the link http://library.lol/main/64D4F62D02A357CEBD789A81F542DD93

A finite length signal can be represented as multiplying the "underlying" unfinite length signal with a rectangular window. In frequency domain this corresponds to a convolution with a sinc function. Since the sinc function has an infinite long extension, naturally, the spectrum of the original signal that is convolved with the sinc function will have an infinite bandwidth.

I know that conclusion. But what I cared is the "effective bandwidth", as defined in the question, rather that the support of the Fourier transform of the signal.

@GeekUESTC so, the question becomes: does the PSD of a sinc fall sufficiently faster than $f^{-2}$ so that the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f^2 \text{sinc}^2(f) ,\mathrm df$ remains bounded?

Sorry,  I have revised the question to make it clearer.

Let me restate the formula for the effective bandwidth (RMS bandwidth) for the case of a real-valued lowpass signal:
$$B^2_{eff}=\frac{\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f^2|S(f)|^2df}{\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|S(f)|^2df}\tag{1}$$
Eq. $(1)$ is easily modified for bandpass or complex-valued signals. For a version of $(1)$ valid for real-valued bandpass signals see this answer. Note the square on the left side of Eq. $(1)$.
The denominator in Eq. $(1)$ is a necessary normalization. Note that by Parseval's theorem we have $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|S(f)|^2df=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|s(t)|^2dt$.
For $B_{eff}$ to be finite we need the integral in the numerator of $(1)$ to converge. Assuming a bounded spectrum, convergence is guaranteed if the integrand decays as $1/f^2$ or faster. Consequently, $|S(f)|$ must decay at least as $1/f^2$.
We know from Fourier theory that the decay in the frequency domain is directly related to smoothness properties in the time domain. A jump discontinuity in the time domain (e.g., a rectangular function) causes a decay proportional to $1/f$ in the spectrum. Hence, in such a case $B_{eff}$ will be infinite. However, a linear decay from a constant value to zero in the time domain (i.e., a triangle or trapezoid) is enough to make the effective bandwidth finite. Smoother time domain functions will result in spectra that decay even faster, and they all have a finite bandwidth.
In sum, it's very easy to construct time domain signals with finite support having a finite effective (RMS) bandwidth.

And if we define effective time duration $T_{\text{eff}}$ as you did in this answer, we get the Heisenberg uncertainty relationship as a lower bound on the product $T_{\text{eff}}^2B_{\text{eff}}^2$ (Eq. (2.6,2) in the answer cited).

Can  you give some references related to the smoothness properties.

@GeekUESTC: This is a standard result in Fourier analysis. You can find it in any book on the Fourier transform. Here is a question on math.se about it.
